# Using BeautifulSoup to extract text from div

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using the following snippet and attempting to parse a section of html from the link below, namely the div appears like:

```
<div id="avg-price" class="price big-price">4.02</div>
<div id="best-price" class="price big-price">0.20</div>
<div id="worst-price" class="price big-price">15.98</div>
```

This is the code that I am attempting to use

```
import requests, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
r = requests.get('https://herf.io/bids?search=tatuaje%20tattoo')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

avgPrice = soup.find("div", {"id": "avg-price"})
lowPrice = soup.find("div", {"id": "best-price"})
highPrice = soup.find("div", {"id": "worst-price"})

print(avgPrice)
print(lowPrice)
print(highPrice)
print("Average Price: {}".format(avgPrice))
print("Low Price: {}".format(lowPrice))
print("High Price: {}".format(highPrice))
```

However, it does not include the price between the divs... the result looks like:

```
<div class="price big-price" id="avg-price"></div>
<div class="price big-price" id="best-price"></div>
<div class="price big-price" id="worst-price"></div>
Average Price: <div class="price big-price" id="avg-price"></div>
Low Price: <div class="price big-price" id="best-price"></div>
High Price: <div class="price big-price" id="worst-price"></div>
```

Any ideas? I'm sure i'm overlooking something small but i'm at wits end right now haha.

Comment: Selenium because javascript

Comment: The values are generated by executing some js codes, and hasn't been included in `r.text`. If you can only use `requests`, make all the same requests as a browser does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course you can, but only when the data did not need to calculate by javascrip. IS NOW!
In this website you can use fiddler to figure out which url did javascrip use to load data, then you can get json or other from it. This is an easy example, after i using fiddler to find out where data came from. Remember you need to set `verify=False` when you use fiddler cert.

```
import requests 

with requests.Session() as se:
    se.headers = {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": "https://herf.io/bids?search=tatuaje%20tattoo",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        }
    data = [
        "search=tatuaje+tattoo",
        "types=",
        "sites=",
    ]

    cookies = {
        "Cookie": "connect.sid=s%3ANYNh5s6LzCVWY8yE9Gra8lxj9OGHPAK_.vGiBmTXvfF4iDScBF94YOXFDmC80PQxY%2FX9FLQ23hYI"}

    url = "https://herf.io/bids/search/open"

    price = "https://herf.io/bids/search/stats"

    req = se.post(price,data="&".join(data),cookies=cookies,verify=False)
    print(req.text)
```

Output

> {"bottomQuarter":4.4,"topQuarter":3.31,"median":3.8,"mean":4.03,"stddev":1.44,"moe":0.08,"good":2.59,"great":1.14,"poor":5.47,"bad":6.91,"best":0.2,"worst":15.98,"count":1121}

Comment: this is a MUCH better way of doing it than what I was looking at!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the text using the `text` attribute:

```
print("Average Price: {}".format(avgPrice.text))
print("Low Price: {}".format(lowPrice.text))
print("High Price: {}".format(highPrice.text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
avgPrice[0].text
```

For the rest, do the same.

Comment: Problem is that he can't scrape the data in the first place. Unless you know how to scrape javascript ran data without selenium?